# Load a huge data from dask dataframe to bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, bigdata, dask, dask-distributed

I read other similar threads and searched Google to find a better way but couldn't find any solution that is acceptable in terms of performance.

I have a very large dask dataframe with 100 partitions and 57 columns. I want to move it to a bigquery table. I have tried 2 ways so far:

```
 dd.compute() # to do compute and then use pandas gbq
 pd.io.gbq.to_gbq(df, BQ_DATASET_NAME_TEMP + "." + BQ_EVENT_TEMP_TB, BQ_PROJECT_NAME, if_exists='append')
```

It takes so long (more than 2 hours)

I also tried to use:

```
dd.to_json('gs://dask_poc/2018-04-18/output/data-*.json')
```

to move dask dataframe to GCS and then move files to bigquery. It take 3 hours to only move dataframe to GCS. Just thought there should be a better way to do it. Any thought?

Comment: What is the size of your data? As for the `to_gbq` method, I think it does not process in parallel the job so this is probably already best performance you'd get.

Comment: @WillianFuks 40 million rows, 57 columns

Answer (score 0):

Your best format for this kind of operation is very likely parquet (`df.to_parquet`), and then send these files. You could *try* to use `df.map_partitions` to send the pieces in parallel using `to_gbq`, but the basic procedure there is slow, and I don't know to what extent BigQuery will allow simultaneous block writes to a table.

Comment: So do the to_parquet for the whole dataframe and then call map_partitions or should I write a function to do to_parquet and to_gbq together and then call map_partitions? @mdurant

Comment: Do it as separate steps, since to_parquet doesn't *return* the data or bytes, they are created on the disc/storage service.